# Binary-Tree in Template

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree

so i want to make a code, that creates a binary tree, that holds data, for example ints like 1,6,2,10,8 and on pop i get the biggest number, and after that it gets deleted from the tree, and on push i can insert a new  element. And this should be in a template so i can easy change the data type i want to hold in the tree. Now i got the tree so  far, without template it is working fine thought, i can add items, and i can print them, but when i try to put it in a template, i get the following error: **use of class template requires template argument list** . What could be the problem? Maybe i am doing it totally wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.

I got the following code so far:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{
struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* lChildptr;
        Node* rChildptr;

        Node(T dataNew)
        {
            data = dataNew;
            lChildptr = NULL;
            rChildptr = NULL;
        }
    };
private:
    Node* root; 

        void Insert(T newData, Node* &theRoot)
        {
            if(theRoot == NULL)
            {
                theRoot = new Node(newData);
                return;
            }

            if(newData < theRoot->data)
                Insert(newData, theRoot->lChildptr);
            else
                Insert(newData, theRoot->rChildptr);;
        }

        void PrintTree(Node* theRoot)
        {
            if(theRoot != NULL)
            {
                PrintTree(theRoot->lChildptr);
                cout<< theRoot->data<<" ";;
                PrintTree(theRoot->rChildptr);
            }
        }

    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }

        void AddItem(T newData)
        {
            Insert(newData, root);
        }

        void PrintTree()
        {
            PrintTree(root);
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        BinaryTree<int> *myBT = new BinaryTree();
        myBT->AddItem(1);
        myBT->AddItem(7);
        myBT->AddItem(1);
        myBT->AddItem(10);
        myBT->AddItem(4);
        myBT->PrintTree();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression

```
new BinaryTree()
```

the identifier `BinaryTree` is a template, not a class. You probably meant

```
new BinaryTree<int>()
```

Comment: It's a class and a template... it's a class template!

Comment: @Marlon, class template? Perhaps. Class? Perhaps not. I need to stop watching Futurama...

Comment: not sure, what you guys are talking about, but it actually works now, so thank you a lot.

Comment: @Toma, don't worry, we were just joking around :)

Comment: umm, i hope i can bother you a bit more, maybe you can help me with that one to, i just read trough the project request , and its like, i have to make this thing i above in the question described, but its like the binary tree should represent a priority queue. And that is why in the request is written that i have to use push and pop to get my data or delete it. So how could i use my Tree as a Priority queue, or is he already one(i think not but who knew)? I hope i could explain it. (should i make this as  new question?)

Comment: @Toma, yes, you should make it a separate question. Anyway, the elements in the tree are already sorted, so to pick up the smallest element, you just find the leftmost element in the tree.