# How to design C++ tree and node classes?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

What I have done is as below, but with this I am having a lot of problems while destructing the tree, and while trying to print the tree (basically anywhere I need to use recursion on the tree).

This is because while trying to call `print` recursively on the left of the right subtrees, my method breaks because my left and right subtrees are actually only `Node`s and not `Tree`s. So, I need to either typecase my Nodes to Trees or I need to create new trees, both of which are ugly solutions.

I think the problem here is with class design. Can you please comment on the same? Thanks!

```
class Node {
    int _data;
public:
    Node* left;       // left child
    Node* right;      // right child
    Node* p;          // parent
    Node(int data) {
        _data = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        p  = NULL;
    }
    ~Node() {
    }
    int d() {
        return _data;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << _data << std::endl;
    }
};

class Tree {
    Node* root;
public:
    Tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }
    Tree(Node* node) {
        root = node;
    }
    ~Tree() {
        delete root->left; // this is NOT RIGHT as
                           // it only deletes the node
                           // and not the whole left subtree
        delete root->right;
        delete root;
    }

    void print(int);
    void add(int);
};
```

Comment: What is `Node *p` supposed to be? A node only has left and right children...

Comment: What is Node::p? Edit: damn you nneonneo :P

Comment: p is the parent pointer.

Comment: Aah. Makes sense. (Probably should be called `*parent` though).

Comment: Check [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186818/binary-tree-in-template), the design is good I think. The destructors are missing there, you just have to do it in the way Rollie pointed in his answer

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just allow `Node` to be your tree class? A non-empty node, by definition, is the root of some tree. This will substantially simplify your code since you don't need to make different cases for `Tree` and `Node`.

Comment: Because I wanted to create a generic Node structure that can be used not just for a tree, but for other data structures as well, for example, a linked list, and for tree to be composed of a set of nodes.

Comment: This does simplify the algorithm, but some concepts differ. For example, you would expect `Tree::Print()` to recursively print all nodes, but not `Node::Print()`, or keeping track of Node count need not be done in every Node if there is a Tree class wrapping everything.

Comment: But your `Node` structures contain *left* and *right* pointers. They can't really be construed as generic! If you want, call them `TreeNode`. Realistically, `TreeNode` and `ListNode` *should* be different classes.

Comment: @Rollie: `Node` would probably benefit from having a recursive printing function. It may also have a non-recursive printing function. The two need not be exclusive. Note too that having `Node`s act like the root of their own tree allows you to examine subtrees in isolation easily, without having to copy their contents to a new `Tree`.

Comment: @nneonneo of course that's true - it's just 2 ways of writing the same function. whether it's part of Node and explicitly PrintRecursive(), part of Tree as Print(), or just an algorithm Print(Node *, bool bRecursive = false). My statement is merely that there is some value in having the tree class; not that it's superior in all respects.  The way OP is describing his Node class though, PrintRecursive() would not be implemented the same way if used in a List class. Re that - what would be the most optimal/elegant way to implement a Tree that can transform into a List?

Comment: Trees and lists are really very different beasts. I don't feel there's any value in trying to unify them. How you implement the linearization of a tree is strongly dependent upon the tree's usage and contents.

Comment: If you visualize a tree on it's side, with the 'root' being on the left, you can think of a 'binary tree' as a general tree where each node is restricted to have at most 2 children, and a linked list as a general tree where each node is restricted to have at most 1 child. They aren't so completely different. When/why would you unify them? A contrived example: you have a list to start, because you care about insertion order. At some point, you no longer care about insertion, but want it sorted, so you convert it to a tree.

Comment: Sure. General tree nodes would have a generic `children` list which you could use to implement lists. But, it's definitely overkill just to implement a list, and won't work if you try to do anything past singly-linked lists (e.g. doubly-linked, circularly-linked, etc.) If you're going to convert from one representation to another, you would probably just reinsert everything into a new tree.

Comment: Isn't circularly-linked just having a `Node * pParent`?

Answer (score 4):

Change the destructor for Node so that it deletes its left and right children. Then for your Tree destructor just delete root, so:

```
~Tree() {
   delete root;
}

~Node() {
   delete left;
   delete right;
}
```

Comment: Other choice is using smart pointers for memory handling, that way you can forget about the destructors, you just have to use std::unique_ptr<Node> instead of Node* in all the declarations. The exception would be the **p** (parent), it should still be Node* as you are not handling memory there, just pointing.

Comment: I haven't used unique_ptr yet, but the doc I'm looking at suggests it's not copyable - this might make rebalancing more difficult. Maybe shared_ptr would be more appropriate?

Comment: shared_ptr introduces a certain risk of accidental cyclic references. You can still move unique_ptr, and its not a big deal. Just do `target = std::move( source );` instead of `target = source;` (*target* and *source* would be of type `std::unique_ptr<Node>`).

Comment: Seems plausible, if I'm understanding though: consider the case where you have a 3 node imbalanced tree (values 3, 2, 1, with 3 being root). Assuming Tree uses `unique_ptr<Node> root;`, to balance you would first have to `Node2->right = move(root);`, then `root = move(Node3->left);` - order seems like it suddenly matters a great deal, as doing the opposite order would delete Node3. Not an insurmountable issue, but a concern nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
~Tree() {
        clear();
        delete root;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        recursive_delete(root);
    }
private:
    void recursive_delete(Node* node)
    {
        if (node!=NULL)
        {
            recursive_delete(node->left);
            recursive_delete(node->right);
            deleteNode(node);
        }
    }
    void deleteNode(Node* node)
    {
        delete node;
        node = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: You are deleting root in `~Tree` and in `recursive_delete`.